# Selector, Event Handling and Keydown event - doesnt work together

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to create a chat box, where, when i input a text and hit enter message is sent and when i press shift+Enter a new line is created.

However, for some reason Keydown event is not getting picked up.
Im not sure if its a code problem or a browser problem or something else.

**chat.js**

```
var chat = {}

chat.throwmsg = function(message) {
if ($.trim(message).length != 0) {
    console.log = 1;
}
}

chat.entry = $('.chat .entry');
chat.entry.bind("keydown", function(e) {
//alert("1");
if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey === false) {
    //chat.throwmsg($(this).val());
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chat">
        <div class="messages">          
        </div>
        <textarea class="entry"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your `keydown` event is most definitely getting picked up; your above code works as expected. `.bind()` is deprecated in jQuery 3, and you should be using `.on()` instead... but it will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ill try it P.S: I only started jquery 3 hours ago

Comment: i just tried 

chat.entry = $('.chat .entry');
chat.entry.on("keydown", function() {
    alert("1");
});

did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code instead...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".entry").keydown(function(event) {
    console.log(event.which);
if (event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) 
{
    console.log(str);
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    var c = event.which;
    str = str.concat(String.fromCharCode(c));
}
});
});
```

Every Keydown not "New line" would concat the character to a string.
And Every "New line" keydown event would reutrn the complete string.

This code can be used for a chat box.